# How do I create 3 columns with responsive text and images?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries, multiple-columns

HTML/CSS beginner here... I have an image with text directly below it. I need to put 3 images with text below next to each other (see example below). I would like there to be equal amounts of space both around and between each column. Image 1 needs to be vertically aligned with Text1, Image2 with Text2 and Image3 with Text3.

```
Image1 Image2 Image3

Text1  Text2 Text3
```

I also need the 3 columns to drop below one another when displayed on a smaller screen.

```
Image1

Text1

Image2

Text2

Image3

Text3
```

I have been using Flexbox but have only managed to display it on a full sized screen. When I make the screen smaller for mobile use the images overlap and no longer line up with the text below. The 3 sections of text keep their position but the images don't seem to want to cooperate. Also, the images and text don't drop down onto the next line. I know...I am probably doing something very wrong here!

I think I can work out where I have been going wrong if someone can provide both the HTML and CSS code for this. If you can add an explanation for your code that would be beyond helpful... but any measure of help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a div (here container) where 3 column will be displayed.
style the container display flex with flex direction row and flex-wrap = wrap.
Wrap is important because when screen will be small then it will display one by one like mobile view.Otherwise it overlap on with other and try to display 3 column together.

2nd you create three div here box each contain image heading and and p tag.
set the style of box flex and direction to column as it appears one under another.
justify and align all the items center

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>



    <style>
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}
img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.box{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width:25rem;
    min-width:18rem;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/36753/flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
            <h1>hello box1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique molestias hic velit, ipsum facere nemo minus distinctio est quidem neque.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/36753/flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
            <h1>box2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique molestias hic velit, ipsum facere nemo minus distinctio est quidem neque.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/36753/flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
            <h1>box3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique molestias hic velit, ipsum facere nemo minus distinctio est quidem neque.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```